# XML Serialization on complex object

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have been looking into how to serialize a C# class into an XML file, but have only found extremely basic examples. I am trying to serialize a class which has other classes encapsulated within it as well.

More specifically I have a Deterministic Finite Automata class in which I encapsulated a List of Transitions, TotalStates, and Alphabet. Where Transitions and States are defined C# classes as well.

After attempting to serialize the class as is, the output XML file is blank, so I am guessing it takes some extra work on my part to get the encapsulated classes to work correctly as well. What do I need to get all encapsulated user defined classes to be placed in the XML as well.

Here is the class I am attempting to serialize. Right now my attributes are not initialized.

```
  public class XMLDoc
    {
        public XMLDoc()
        {
            AllStates = new List<State>();
            alphabet = new List<char>();
            transitions = new List<Transition>();

            alphabet.Add('1');
            alphabet.Add('0');


        }
        List<State> AllStates; // Our set of all States
        List<Char> alphabet;    // Our alphabet set
        List<Transition> transitions; //; Our set of transitions
        State startState, finalState;
    }
```

Here is a State class

```
  public class State
    {
        public State(int value)
        {
            id = value;
            type = StateType.Normal;
        }

        public void makeInitial()
        {
            type = StateType.Initial;
        }

        public void makeFinal()
        {
            type = StateType.Final;
        }
        public int getID()
        {
            return this.id;
        }

        int id;
        StateType type;

        List<Transition> transitions; // This list is going to be all transitions that have this State as the Initial value
    }
```

And here is a Transition class

```
  public class Transition
    {
        public Transition(State initial, Char accept, State final)
        {
            this.init = initial;
            this.acceptor = accept;
            this.final = final;
        }

        public int getInit(){
            return init.getID();
        }

        public int getFinal()
        {
            return final.getID();
        }

        public Char getAcceptor()
        {
            return acceptor;
        }
        State init; // This is the state we are transitioning
        Char acceptor; // This is the accepting alphabet value
        State final; // This is the state init becomes after accepting the acceptor
    }
```

In the end, I want the XML in the form similar to this

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>

<!-- XML Definition of a DFA by Matt Hintzke -->
<DFA>
    <!-- This defines the all used states in the DFA -->
    <STATES-SET>
        <STATE>q0</STATE>
        <STATE>q1</STATE>
        <STATE>q2</STATE>
        <STATE>q3</STATE>
    </STATES-SET>

    <!-- This defines the alphabet -->
    <ALPHABET>
        <CHARACTER>1</CHARACTER>
        <CHARACTER>0</CHARACTER>
    </ALPHABET>

    <!-- This defines all transitions -->
    <TRANSITION-SET>

        <!-- A transition block represents all transitions that can be made from a single initial state -->
        <TRANSITION-BLOCK>
            <!-- Hence, this block defines all transitions from the INIT-STATE q0 to any other states -->
            <INIT-STATE>q0</INIT-STATE>
            <!-- A transition represents any ACCEPTOR character from the INIT-STATE to some FINAL state -->
            <TRANSITION>
                <ACCEPTOR>1</ACCEPTOR>
                <FINAL>q1</FINAL>
            </TRANSITION>

            <TRANSITION>
                <ACCEPTOR>0</ACCEPTOR>
                <FINAL>q2</FINAL>
            </TRANSITION>
        </TRANSITION-BLOCK>



        <TRANSITION-BLOCK>
            <INIT-STATE>q1</INIT-STATE>
            <TRANSITION>
                <ACCEPTOR>1</ACCEPTOR>
                <FINAL>q0</FINAL>
            </TRANSITION>

            <TRANSITION>
                <ACCEPTOR>0</ACCEPTOR>
                <FINAL>q3</FINAL>
            </TRANSITION>
        </TRANSITION-BLOCK>


        <TRANSITION-BLOCK>
            <INIT-STATE>q2</INIT-STATE>
            <TRANSITION>
                <ACCEPTOR>1</ACCEPTOR>
                <FINAL>q3</FINAL>
            </TRANSITION>

            <TRANSITION>
                <ACCEPTOR>0</ACCEPTOR>
                <FINAL>q0</FINAL>
            </TRANSITION>
        </TRANSITION-BLOCK>



        <TRANSITION-BLOCK>
            <INIT-STATE>q3</INIT-STATE>
            <TRANSITION>
                <ACCEPTOR>1</ACCEPTOR>
                <FINAL>q2</FINAL>
            </TRANSITION>

            <TRANSITION>
                <ACCEPTOR>0</ACCEPTOR>
                <FINAL>q1</FINAL>
            </TRANSITION>
        </TRANSITION-BLOCK>
    </TRANSITION-SET>


    <!-- This defines all starting states -->
    <STARTING-SET>
        <STATE>q0</STATE>
    </STARTING-SET>

    <!-- This defines all final states -->
    <FINAL-SET>
        <STATE>q3</STATE>
    </FINAL-SET>
</DFA>
```

And lastly, here is the code to serialize...

```
    public void Serialize()
    {
        XMLDoc mydoc = new XMLDoc();

        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XMLDoc));
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("test.xml");
        ser.Serialize(writer, mydoc);
        writer.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code you're using.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You're trying to XML serialize an object. If you want us to help you, you're going to have to show the actual code that does the serializing.

Comment: Initial observation - you cannot serialise fields, only properties. Plus, can we see your actual serialisation code?

Comment: added everything related

Answer (score 0):

Those classes will not serialise because you have private fields, but you need to use public properties.

UPDATE:
Below is a sample which runs in LinqPad, based on your classes (I stripped out the methods as they are irrelevant for serialisation):

```
void Main()
{
     XMLDoc mydoc = new XMLDoc();

        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XMLDoc));
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"D:\test.xml");
        ser.Serialize(writer, mydoc);
        writer.Close();
}

public class XMLDoc
    {
        public XMLDoc()
        {
            AllStates = new List<State>();
            alphabet = new List<char>();
            transitions = new List<Transition>();
            alphabet.Add('1');
            alphabet.Add('0');
        }
        public List<State> AllStates{get;set;} // Our set of all States
        public List<Char> alphabet{get;set;}    // Our alphabet set
        public List<Transition> transitions{get;set;} //; Our set of transitions
        public State startState{get;set;}
        public State finalState{get;set;}
    }


     public class State
     {
      //note - no explicitly defined default ctor here
      //that is OK as long as you don't have any other ctors defined.
      //although bear in mind that you probably should have one
      //to intialise 'type' and 'transitions'
      public int id{get;set;}
      public StateType type{get;set;}
      public List<Transition> transitions{get;set;} // This list is going to be all transitions that have this State as the Initial value
     }


    public class StateType
    {
      //did not have any code for this class...
    }

    public class Transition
    {
        public Transition(){} //must have default ctor to serialise.
        public Transition(State initial, Char accept, State final)
        {
            this.init = initial;
            this.acceptor = accept;
            this.final = final;
        }        
        public State init{get;set;} // This is the state we are transitioning
        public Char acceptor{get;set;} // This is the accepting alphabet value
        public State final{get;set;} // This is the state init becomes after accepting the acceptor
    }
```

This produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XMLDoc xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <AllStates />
  <alphabet>
    <char>49</char>
    <char>48</char>
  </alphabet>
  <transitions />
</XMLDoc>
```

Note that you should check up on the various [Serialisation Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that you can use to control the "shape" of the generated XML, although to be honest I am not 100% certain you can achieve the format you want with the default XMLSerialiser.

You might consider having a look at the [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class which can be used from `System.Xml.Linq` (Linq to XML) to build XML documents very easily - it might suit you better for the type of format you want.

Hope that helps.

Comment: so will this mean I have to make every property in all my classes public?

Comment: Either that or write your own custom serialiser.(which is not that hard to do)

Comment: when I added public in front of those, my XMLSerializer() constructor broke on InvalidOperationException

Comment: @Matt, the inner exception you got would have shown that Transition was missing a default ctor. I have updated my answer with a working sample

Comment: oh thank you, but after adding that to mine, it does not change anything